# [SwiftUI]: Not transparency behind TabBar

Tags: swiftui, transparent, tabbar

I just started to learn SwiftUI, and I have an issue: why my TabBar isn't transparent when scrolling ?

[image]

Here's my code :

```
var body: some View {
    VStack {
        ZStack(alignment: .bottomTrailing) {
            ScrollViewReader { scroll in
                // my bubbles here
            }
            .padding(.bottom, 70)
            .scrollDismissesKeyboard(.interactively)
        
            ZStack {
                HStack {
                    TextField("Type your message", text: $newMessage)
                        .padding(9)
                        .background(
                            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 19)
                                .foregroundColor(Color(.systemGray6))
                        )
                }
                .padding()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you and have a great day !

Answer (score 2):

To have a semi-transparent tab bar you will have to place your text field and send button in a `ToolbarItem` like so:

```
var body: some View {
    ScrollView {
        ForEach(0..<100) {_ in
            Capsule().fill(Color.blue)
                .frame(height: 50)
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                .padding(.horizontal)
        }
    }
    .toolbar {
        ToolbarItem(placement: .bottomBar) {
            HStack {
                TextField("Type your message", text: .constant(""))
                    .textFieldStyle(.roundedBorder)
                Button("Send", action: {})
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Which gives you the blurry background both on tool bar and tab bar:

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Hello, thank you for your response ! I have another issue now https://postimg.cc/cKbsc9j8 the keyboard hides TextInput, thanks ;)